# I am trying to send an array of loader function to my route it throws an error Handler is not a funtion in a reactJs application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, loader

This is my app .js which has a route

```
async function landingPageContentLoader() {
  const url = AppConstants.landingPageDataAPI;
  const response = await DataService.get(url,AppConstants.emptyString,AppConstants.emptyString)
  return response;   
}
async function skillsLoader() {
  const url = AppConstants.exploreSkillsGetAPI;
  const response = await DataService.get(url,AppConstants.emptyString,AppConstants.emptyString);
  console.log(response);
  return response;   
}
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  
  {
    path: AppConstants.skills,
    element:<SkillsPage/>,
    loader: [landingPageContentLoader,skillsLoader]
  },
```

Inside my Page I am fetching data through useLoaderData

```
export const SkillsPage = ()=>{

  const {landingPageContentLoader,skillsLoader} = useLoaderData();
}
```

[image]
this is the error I receive

Comment: Route loaders are functions, not arrays. What are you trying to accomplish overall?

Comment: I have to make two HTTP request to fetch data for two components on my page, I wanted to put each request in a loader function and pass that as an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route loaders are functions, not arrays. If you need to call two loader functions then I think you could create a third loader function that invokes both and collects and returns their response data.

Example:

```js
async function landingPageContentLoader() {
  const url = AppConstants.landingPageDataAPI;
  const response = await DataService.get(
    url,
    AppConstants.emptyString,
    AppConstants.emptyString
  );

  return response;   
}

async function skillsLoader() {
  const url = AppConstants.exploreSkillsGetAPI;
  const response = await DataService.get(
    url,
    AppConstants.emptyString,
    AppConstants.emptyString
  );

  return response;   
};

const skillsPageLoader = async () => {
  return Promise.all([landingPageContentLoader(), skillsLoader()]);
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  
  {
    path: AppConstants.skills,
    element: <SkillsPage/>,
    loader: skillsPageLoader,
  },
]);
```

```js
export const SkillsPage = () => {
  const [landingPageContentLoader, skillsLoader] = useLoaderData();

  ...
}
```

Comment: This approach of defining the two loader function in an array of promises worked